# Ordered list displaying all <li>s as number 1 in Explorer 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

I've been alerted to a strange problem in IE7 that I can't locate a solution for. I have a standard ordered list formatted properly, with all opening and closing tags intact.

```
<ol>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

All browsers display the list properly except Explorer 7 which renders the list as below:

```
1. Item 1
1. Item 2
1. Item 3
1. Item 4
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? [Here's a link](http://www.ovpr.uga.edu/docs/policies/osp/facility-admin-costs) to the list. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Nudge: I added a finding to my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue before. The following fixed my issue.

```
ol li {
  margin-left: 2em;
  display: list-item;
  list-style: inside decimal-leading-zero;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000687.html

> This happens when a width is added to
>   the "LI" tags in an ordered list.
>   Internet Explorer 7 will not increment
>   the numbers.

Comment: I tried with adding a width on the `li` tags, but that alone doesn't cause the problem, so there has to be something more that comes into play.

Comment: Worked for me. What an odd bug.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qGh9N/) in IE7, and it displays as it should.

Try to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) the page to see if there are any errors elsewhere in the code.

#### Edit:

I managed to see the problem in IE 9 in IE 7 mode, and playing around with the styles I found this:

Remove the `zoom: 1;` style from the `#content LI` rule in `universal.css`, and the numbering returns to normal.